# mysql query that can be used instead mysql_num_rows

Tags: php, mysql

I want to know how i can write a mysql query which checks how many record exists in other table ?

```
table 1 : names

id name
-- ----
4  john
5  mike
6  jenny

table 2 : cars

id name_id car
-- ------- ---
1   4      bmw
2   4      wv
3   6      honda
```

`query = "SELECT * FROM names WHERE id = '4'"` <- in that query i also want to check how many records there are in the cars table or if there is any ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT names.id, name, COUNT(car) as 'cars'
FROM names LEFT JOIN cars ON names.id = cars.nameid 
WHERE names.id = '4'
GROUP BY names.id, name
```

Comment: this is more efficient that using a sub query.

Comment: @Hamish, OP should try all solutions and draw his conclusions from there. Using SQL Server, performing the group by in the join is twice as fast.

Comment: The title and tags specify MySQL. In current MySQL versions subqueries are *very* poorly optimized. Refer http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/10/25/mysql-limitations-part-3-subqueries/. Hence the upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Add the amount of cars for each person in an additional `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT  n.*, c.cnt
FROM    names n
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
          SELECT  name_id, cnt = COUNT(*)
          FROM    cars
          GROUP BY
                  name_id
        ) c ON c.name_id = n.id
WHERE   ID = 4
```

If performance is an issue, you can add the condition to the left join at the expense of maintainability.

```
SELECT  n.*, c.cnt
FROM    names n
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
          SELECT  name_id, cnt = COUNT(*)
          FROM    cars
          WHERE   name_id = 4 -- Condition needs to be updated in two places
          GROUP BY
                  name_id
        ) c ON c.name_id = n.id
WHERE   ID = 4
```

Comment: don't know what Ahmet vardar is expecting, but with this query, he doesn't get "mike" with "0" cars... i think the left join that JonVD posted would be the better solution (as it lists all names, the ones without cars, too)

Comment: @oezi, you are right, I've changed the INNER to LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT n.*, COUNT(c.*) FROM names n, cars c WHERE n.id = 4
```

You can also name the column:

```
SELECT n.*, COUNT(c.*) AS `num_cars` FROM names n, cars c WHERE n.id = 4
```

Comment: That would return all records where the cars.id = 4 not the names.id = 4, a simple change though